# How do I fix error: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead" in this code?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //API Key: 5ca10b2d20a545099a108a3aeceb329c
    //url: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5ca10b2d20a545099a108a3aeceb329c


    // model

    struct Source: Decodable {
        var id: String
        var name: String
    }

    struct Articles: Decodable {
        var source: Source
        var author: String
        var title: String
        var description: String
        var url: String
        var urlToImage: String
        var publishedAt: String
        var content: String

    }

    struct JSONDescription: Decodable {
        var status: String
        var totalResults: Int
        var articles: Articles
    }


    guard let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5ca10b2d20a545099a108a3aeceb329c") else { return }


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//            print(dataAsString)

        do {
        let jsonDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONDescription.self, from: data)
            print(jsonDescription.totalResults)
        }
        catch let jsonError {
            print("Json Error:", jsonError)
        }
}.resume()
}
}
```

What I expected to see was the JSON data returned here: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=5ca10b2d20a545099a108a3aeceb329c

You can put it into this formatter to make is readable: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

I thought I did everything correctly. Have I built my model wrong? I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Instead of using the `try? JSONDecoder()`, just use `try` and add a catch block. In it, print the error. That might help give you more information on what's up.

Comment: I changed my URL session to this: 

           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//            print(dataAsString)

            do {
            let jsonDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONDescription.self, from: data)
                print(jsonDescription.totalResults)
            }
            catch let jsonError {
                print("Json Error:", jsonError)
            }
}.resume()
}
}

Comment: Now I get this error: Json Error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. **Expected** is the *wrong* type you proposed, **found** is the *right* type, **Dictionary<String, Any>** is represented by a struct or class.

Comment: Also, just wanted to point out - are you sure you want to publish that API key here publicly?

Comment: Mattie, thanks for the heads up on the API key. Normally, yes, it's bad practice to publish your api key,, but this is just an news api that I'm using to learn how APIs work. I'm not even doing a front end. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the help of the error returned, and looking at the data, it seems that "articles" is an array.

Here's what I'd try:

- Rename your `Articles` struct to `Article`
- Change JSONDescription's `articles` property from `Articles` to `[Article]`

I didn't notice any other errors in the data mapping, but hopefully this gets you closer.

Comment: Yes, that basically did it. Thanks Mattie!

(Also, I needed to make the declared values optionals because some of the json was returning nil values).

Comment: Great - glad that was helpful!